# How to display the manual in Gtk?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm building a Gtk3 application using Python. I was wondering if there was a standard way for building and displaying inline help (the manual). More specifically:

1. What text format should I use for storing it (html? XML? other?)
2. How should I display it? I need to be able to browse the contents, the search for specific terms, to display formatted text with images, and to open the help window at a specific location when the user request online help about a specific part of the user interface.

Finally, in the ideal case, it should be cross-platform (e.g. I plan to port it to Windows)

Comment: On Linux you should investigate man pages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page

Comment: Expect to have as much work with the help system as you had with the app itself... :P

Comment: @SimpleCoder Off course, I need to build a man page. But that wasn't what this question is about!

Comment: @CharlesBrunet: No? It seems to solve at least problem #1.

Comment: @SimpleCoder I think man page is good to describe command line options, and what the program is for, but not for telling how to use a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't know your app needed to be multiplatform. Be careful, because GTK3 on Windows is quite difficult to use for the time being (AFAIK there are no official installer either for GTK3 nor PyGObject on Windows, only community stuff).

On Linux, GNOME uses [Yelp](https://live.gnome.org/Yelp) to handle documentation, but I don't know if it has been ported to Windows.

Comment: Thank for the hint about GTK3 and Windows. I will see how it will be at the time I'll be ready to do the port...

Comment: In fact, using yelp in Linux wouldn't be a problem, if I also can use a native help viewer on Windows (and eventually OS X) with the same help files. Do you have any hints about that?

Comment: Not sure there's a [Mallard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallard_%28documentation%29) doc viewer on Windows, but there are alternatives to it (follow the Mallard link).